# Is it possible to reuse app name when old app removed from app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

We have an app on iOS App Store (app1) and it's name is, say "AAA". Is it possible to use the name "AAA" again if we remove the old app (app1)?

Comment: Email Apple and try the DevForums (or if you have, at least mention that you tried and didn't get a response). Any answers you get here will be suspect.

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377534/deleting-an-app-in-itunes-connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. If you are getting the error message even after deleting the old app call Apple and ask them to reset it for you. Explain the situation and then will sort it for you.

Answer (score 6):

Don't delete the old app from your iTunes Connect portal, or you may lose the ability to use the name.  Instead, submit an update to the old app with a different new name.  After it is accepted, submit your new app reusing the old name.

Comment: We will not remove the old app. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's your own app, then why don't you just update it, even if it's a totally different app idea, you can still update it with same old App Id.

Comment: We have situations that we cannot update the old app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The app name & app ID are 2 independent things. As medopal suggests you could release your app as an update to the old even if it is something entirely new. Alternatively you could create a new app ID & use that for your new app even if it has the same name as the old app.

HTH, Pedro :)