# Can We Delete an App from iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, bundle-identifier

Hi I created an app with a bundle ID but that App was rejected from Apple, Now I need to upload a new App but with the same bundle ID, but the rejected one keeps holding it, I need to delete this App and upload new one, I tried this link

[Deleting an app in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377534/deleting-an-app-in-itunes-connect)

but all it says is to deselect all from sales section, I also tried changing it bundle-ID but to no avail,..is there any other way to get rid of this rejected app and upload a new one with the same bundleID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to add a new app,but was able to upload a new build by updating the build number , I also had to update the Version, because the new Build contained In-APp purchases, any ways, it went smoothly after that, The In-app purchase was causing me the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

First of all,

**Bundle ID**: A reverse DNS string that precisely identifies a single app.

**Bundle ID search string**: it is used to match a set of bundle IDs, where each bundle ID identifies a single app. For example, if the bundle ID search string is com.mycompany.MyApp or a wildcard such as com.mycompany.*, then it will match the bundle ID com.mycompany.MyApp.

**App ID**: A string that identifies one or more apps from a single team. An App ID consists of a bundle ID search string preceded by the Team ID, a 10-character string generated by Apple to uniquely identify a team.

Bundle Id is Unique, it can't be reused as exact.

If you had created this app Id from one account (com.mycompany.MyApp) , you can't create the same app Id from the other account. However, you will still be able to create a new one as com.mycompany.MyApp1 like or so. There should be atleast 1 character difference in the app Id's.

Also, App IDs cannot be removed because once allocated they need to stay alive, so that another App ID doesn't accidentally collide with a previously existing App ID.

Comment: I dnt want to remove app id I want to remove the app from iTunes Connect

Comment: You could release your app as an update to the old even if it is something entirely new. are you adding version no? are you adding new updated version on itunesconnect ?

Comment: If you have delete the application still than APPLE does not allow using same bundle id to create application as it counts that bundle as used. So you need to create new ID for new app. I Suggest you create an update. This situation happens to almost everyone. Approach is to upload an updated version

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot re-use a bundle id. it is unique for each app created on iTunes.
in fact, if i am not mistaken itunes clearly warns about not being able to change bundle id once the app is created.

Comment: yes but the app is not yet live ,iTunes  warns about not being able to chane once its live, my app is not live

Comment: I guess that does'nt really matter - creating an app in itunesconnect (even though its rejected/approved) makes that bundle identifier unique.

Answer (score 1):

The submitted app is holding you up because you have not yet rejected the binary so you can replace it with a new one.

You can submit an app with the same BundleID by first rejecting the binary of the first one.

Please refer to the guide and look for the Rejecting Your Binary article (below): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34

**Rejecting Your Binary**

Rejecting a binary removes your app version from Apple’s review queue and changes its status to Developer Rejected. You can then move your app back to Waiting For Upload (See “Uploading Your Binary”). When you resubmit your binary, the review process starts over from the beginning.

You can reject the binary you’ve submitted if its status is any of the following:

- Missing Screenshot (iOS only)
- Waiting For Export Compliance
- Waiting For Review
- In Review
- Pending Developer Release
- Pending Apple Release

If your app’s status is not one of these, see “Deleting an App.”

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't delete an application from iTunes.

Comment: I Know, we cant kindly see my answer above