# iTunes Connect - Remove apps

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

How can I delete a application from "My Apps"?

When I press the app, the then press "More", all I see is: "About This App", View on App Store" and "Transfer App". There is no "Delete App".

The game status is "1.0 Prepare for Submission".

Comment: @rdurand - But if i can't delete it from iTunes Connect, then i cannot either delete it from "Cerificates -> Identifiers -> App IDs"?

Comment: sorry, I answered too quickly. See my answer below

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153931/is-it-a-way-to-remove-app-from-itunes-connect

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377534/deleting-an-app-in-itunes-connect

Answer (score 3):

From the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html):

> **Deleting an App**
>
> If you’ve created an app in iTunes Connect that you no longer need to manage, you can delete it from iTunes Connect.
>
> Apps can’t be deleted if they are part of a Game Center group, in an app bundle, or currently displayed on a store. You’ll want to remove the app from sale or from the group if you want to delete it. See Removing an App from Sale or Removing an App from a Group in Game Center Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect. Apps that have not been approved yet can’t be deleted; instead, reject the app. See Removing a Build from Review.
>
> Important:  If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a binary or set up this app for the iAd App Network, your bundle ID can’t be reused.

Here's how to delete your app:

> **To delete an app from the store and iTunes Connect:**
>
> 1. Open the App Details page for the app, as described in [Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).
> 2. Make sure that the app status allows deletion. You can delete your app **if there is at least one approved version of the app** and the latest version status is one of the following:
>
>    - Prepare for Submission
>    - Invalid Binary
>    - Developer Rejected
>    - Rejected
>    - Metadata Rejected
>    - Developer Removed From Sale
>    - Removed from Sale
>
> If your app has a different status, you can delete the app by first rejecting the binary or by removing the app from sale. See [Viewing and Changing Your App’s Status and Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW1).
>
> 3. Click the More menu and select Delete App.
>
> If the Delete App button isn’t displayed, check that you’re the team agent and that the app is in one of the statuses that allow the app to be deleted.
>
> 4. A confirmation dialog appears. Click Delete.

**Although Apple talks about "Deleting an app from iTunes Connect", I'm pretty sure deletion as explained here will not make your app disappear from iTunes Connect, simply from the AppStore. I don't believe there's a way to make your app disappear from iTunes Connect.**

Comment: That's because you aren't allowed to delete it in that stage. Read the question links I added in the comment below your question.

Comment: @Michal  ..Oh my app hasn't been approwed, because there is no app. So i can never delete it then?

Comment: I added a comment at the end of my answer

Comment: @rdurand That kinda sucks tho.. I bet there are plenty of people that want to simply remove their "apps" from itunes connect..

Comment: Maybe, but creating an app in iTunes Connect is probably not a light operation on Apple's side, as it also registers the name you choose on the AppStore, to prevent other apps to use the same name..

Comment: @rdurand But in apple developer member center -> certificate -> identifiers -> app ids i cannot delete the apps. It says it apperas to be in use by the app store, so it can not be removed at this time.

Comment: @olepierre Yes, to delete the app ID you should delete the app from iTunes Connect, and to do so you must have at least one approved version of the app..

Comment: @rdurand Well, the i cant delete it, because it's not even a app i have or have ever had.