# Delete not reviewed app from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I created application in iTunes connect and download archive for beta testing. But I make a mistake in application name and now I want to delete it and create new with correct name. There are many similar topics, but the solution to deselect all countries in Pricing not working for me.

> The following error(s) occurred:
>   You must select at least one App Store territory in which you want to make your app available.

In apple documentation it is also said, that application should be reviewed at least 1 time to be rejected by developer, does it mean that I should send my app for review and only after it I would be able to delete my app? It is kinda stupid. At the moment my app has status "Prepare for Submission" and has not released version, only beta testing.

Comment: Did you make mistake in itunes connect name or project name?

Comment: I create app in itunes connect with wrong Bunde ID, I can change the app name, but not Bundle ID, so when I am trying to change app name in xCode -> the bundle ID change 2 and I can't download it to iTunes Connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to create new application in iTunes Connect with new bundle id (you should also generate new in developer portal). Because you can't update it:

> The bundle ID must match the one you used in Xcode. It can't be
>   changed after you upload your first build.

You can upload your binary and send to review and remove your wrong application when it will pass review.

Also check this question, @pion answer with comments: [Deleting an app in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377534/deleting-an-app-in-itunes-connect)

They provided some workaround, maybe it will help you.